# svgElement.getBoundingClientRect() always returns zeros while testing with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I created some svg element and want to determine its size with

```
svgElement.getBoundingClientRect()
```

My code works if the svgElement is appended to the document with

```
document.body.appendChild(svgElement)
```

**and if I run the code in the browser** (google chrome).

However, while testing with **nodejs** and jest, the width and the height of the resulting bounding rect are always zero.

=>What can I do to correctly run the code with nodejs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nodejs uses jsdom and `getBoundingClientRect` is only implemented to return the right properties, but not the right values.

Also see https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/653

For the tests the method `getBoundingClientRect` should be mocked, for example with:

```
spyOn(svgElement,'getBoundingClientRect').and.returnValue({
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 10
});
```

Comment: yes, it's true. The reason: JSDOM is not actually render engine(does not calculate width based on content, does not stretch or clip elements etc). So we should mock that method as well as [`offset*`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/135) and [`scroll*`/`client*`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/353)